# Placing the foreign key in rails model belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations

I am a beginner to rails framework. I have a fundamental question.

I am trying to define some models and their association referring the popular rails guides. My association looks like below.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :head
end

class Head < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

Here, I need to add the foreign_key (Persons's primary key) in the table 'head'.

Now, if I need to get the 'head' of a 'person', rails need to scan through the head table and match the person_id.

The straight forward way I would think is to add the foreign key in 'person' table. Then I can directly refer the 'head' from 'person' with it's ID.

It appears that rails convention is not performance friendly. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Ari!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the migration to add the column containing the foreign key, it is highly recommended to [add an index](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index) on this column. This way, the database will efficiently find the Head from the `person_id` (as efficiently then a search by its `id`).

```
add_index :heads, :person_id
```

If it's a one-to-one association, you can even add the `unique` option (unless your application accepts conjoined twins :-) ):

```
add_index :heads, :person_id, :unique => true
```

I suggest you to have a look to this 2 articles on where to use indexes:

- http://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-index-your-associations
- http://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-choosing-additional-indexes

Comment: Wow! That was really quick.

Thanks a lot for the response. 

I understand that indexing will solve the performance issue here. But, aren't we creating an additional index that can be avoided if we swap the has_one & belongs_to associations in the example. id is anyway indexed.

I am just trying to clear my understanding here, not to debate on rails design :)

Comment: You're right: if your application use the relation "unidirectionally", from Person to Head, you can set the foreign key in the Person model, and save an index. If you use the relation in both directions, it's better to have an index (wherever you put the foreign key).

Answer (score 1):

Re: It appears that rails convention is not performance friendly. Am I missing something here?

Yes. Rails is designed for production sites. So it includes many performance features. As @Baldrick says, the answer to your specific concern is to always add an index for foreign key fields.

Adding an index for each foreign key field is needed, for performance reasons, for any SQL dbms application, no matter the language. Note that the index is added to the *database,* not to the MVC layers (Rails).

Rails itself includes additional performance features including sql results caching, optional fragment and page caching, and more.

Rails 3.2 includes the [slow query features](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-explain). These enable Rails to automatically show you the queries which are slow. You can then focus on fixing them as appropriate.